# How can we reduce the PR load on our team?

Tags: code-reviews, pull-requests

We are using microservices(read a lot of GIT repositories) and our department has 90+ java developers. All of them write code which mean there are a lot of PR`s every day. We are using BitBucket and Also we have a self written bot that listen BB events and can sends a PR review notification to slack.

Notify every developers about each created PR looks like PR DDOS. So we configure bot to use two groups: mandatory approvers(PR can't be merge without their approve) and others. There were about 15 mandatory approvers. In this case each PR has to be approved by 1 mandatory and 3 other reviewers to be merged.
But daily amount of PR's is too big and mandatory approvers still got a lot of notifications which stops their main work. It was our first approach and we decided to declined it.

The second approach is to split all developers by groups(15-20 devs per group) within related business area and don't use mandatory approvers. In this case each PR has to be approved by five reviewers. After that it's ready to merge. Also such attempt should increase overall expertise cause devs from one business are can review PR more thoroughly.

Right now bot is sending notification to all participant from group to which author belongs. It spread load to all devs from group. The amount of PR's to review changes day by day but usually it is still quietly big.

Maybe there are another approaches use in your company. Just curios to know. Maybe you have some ideas how to rebuild review process.

One of the next steps we are thinking about is to decrease the number of devs in one group which decrease daily amount of PR's for one dev.

Comment: What is your field of work? 4-5 reviewers is probably ok (and maybe even required) for medical or aerospace code...

Comment: 5 reviewers seems a lot to me, even in the formentioned fields - can you elobarate on this?

Comment: Yep, maybe 5 reviewers is too much and we can decrease it to 3. We are developing a bank software. The number 5 was like a random choice for first iteration.

Comment: I worked on a (modular) monolith project with 40-ish developers. Developers were divided into 6 teams. Each team owned some modules. We only required 2 reviewers for internal changes and an additional one from the external team in case we wanted to change something that did not belong to the current team scope.

Comment: @HieuLe how do you choose which one should review particular request? Do these two reviewers will get direct notification(in slack, mail, whatever)? Will others developers also receives notifications about new PR's where they are not mandatory reviewers?

Comment: @Mirian we didn't get notifications for new PRs. We used Jira board to see if any tickets waited for another review. There were no pre-assigned reviewers unless in specific tickets that the whole team agreed (in the planning meeting) that a specific person in the team is the mandatory reviewer. In short, only people involved in the PR (the developer, the reviewers, and one have comments) are notified about the changes of the PR.

Answer (score 7):

> In this case each PR has to be approved by five reviewers.

This is your biggest problem. Reduce this number to two or at absolute maximum, three. If you don't trust that two developers on your team can effectively review code from another developer on your team, *get better reviewers*.

> (15-20 devs per group)

This is your second biggest problem. Your teams should be aligned around your microservices, and the team responsible for each microservice should be reviewing the code for that service; they are the domain experts after all. That means a *maximum* of say 6-7 people in each group ("two pizza team") - give them actual ownership of each service, rather than trying to distribute it around your team of 90 developers.

Comment: The term *Domain Expert* typically refers to someone working in that particular domain. It’s the person developers go to with questions. Surely developers will gain a lot of knowledge about a particular domain when creating software for it, but that doesn’t make them domain experts.

Comment: @RikD Thinking of microservices as small, bounded domains here.

Comment: I agree with @RikD, even in high autonomous microservice teams, developers are not domain experts. They are technical experts, they know much about their current domain, but they are not the person who makes final decisions if business logic is implemented correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If every pull request has five reviewers, then the average developer’s workload includes five reviews for every pull request they produce. That’s a lot of time in my day spent on pull requests.

I wonder how much benefit you get from that.

Comment: Yep, looks like 5 is too much. It was our first iteration. Will decrease it to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the number of reviewers, the way developers are notified about PRs might be an issue. Interruptions are bad. Actually, **REALLY BAD**, in bold uppercase.

Try to find ways that developers can switch from "development mode" into "review mode" and get PRs to review only when in review mode. Don't interrupt their development work. It might be good for each developer to make that switch only once or very few times per day. You need to decide whether reviewers are free to pick PRs (for example those covering areas where they have most expertise, or those from new colleagues who may need some guidance about the product) or assign using some random (and hopefully fair) scheme.